# Emacs info manual missing in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package-management, 17.10, debian, emacs, documentation

On Ubuntu 17.10, installing Emacs via $sudo apt install emacs
and then trying to view the Emacs manual using C-h r fails with error "Info file emacs does not exist" The same set of instructions on Ubuntu 16.04 works and one ends up with a local copy of the GNU emacs manual. Did the documentation get delegated to another package or is missing on purpose?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Emacs documentation is in the package `emacs25-common-non-dfsg`.

Comment: Why the packages would do that? Why doesn't the package name is at least something like `emacs-manuals` or `emacs-info-manuals`?

Comment: Ouch. GFDL (GNU Free Documentation License) is not compatible with DFSG (Debian Free Software Guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

The Emacs documentation has moved to the package `emacs-common-non-dfsg`.